# IPhone Google Location API V3 Show Own created location on Google Map

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

how to show the own created location on Google MAP ?

i have registered google location api and added new location on google with the help of Google place api v3.

i can get success response from google for adding new place on google.

i tried to fetch same location by passing place_id and refance value , than i can able to get the location information in responce from google , but when i searched same location on google map with "my created place name" or "place address" than it can not able to show me that new place which i created by place api v3.

below is my code for adding new location google by google place api v3.

Code For Add New place on google ,

```
NSString *str1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><PlaceAddRequest><location><lat>23.025651</lat><lng>72.507753</lng></location><accuracy>50</accuracy><name>Test Place on Gmap</name><phone_number>(91) 2339374 423000</phone_number><address>201 - Dev Arc Mall, Nr. ISKCON Bridge, S. G. Highway, Ahmedabad, Gujarat, India</address><type>food</type><website>http://www.testing.co.in/</website><language>en-US</language></PlaceAddRequest>"];

NSLog(@"str1=====%@",str1);


NSString *str2 = [str1 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSData *requestdata = [NSData dataWithBytes:[str2 UTF8String] length:[str2 length]];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestdata length]];


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/add/xml?sensor=false&key=AIzaSyDtsmfnmSKSgDGK4s5CJTNCV2GzZDtwoyE"]];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[NSData dataWithBytes:[str1 UTF8String] length:[str1 length]]];

//NSURLConnection *placesConn =[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
NSData *returndata = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnstr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returndata encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
NSLog(@"returnstr: %@",returnstr);
```

By doing this code i can able to create place on google , now to fetch that same address by type i am unable to get this place in response , but same detail i can able to get by place_id or reference.

```
currentCentre.latitude = 23.025651;
currentCentre.longitude = 72.507753;


// Fetch own created Location information
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=qgYvCi0wMDAwMDAzMzJjNjgxNjkwOjM5NWU5YjNhMTA1OjIwNmZhZjdmODcxNzlkZWM&key=AIzaSyDtsmfnmSKSgDGK4s5CJTNCV2GzZDtwoyE"];



NSURL *googleRequestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[url        stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


// Retrieve the results of the URL.
dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: googleRequestURL];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
});
```

but i am unable to see this address or place on google map.

please help me for this.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to show pin on the map for your location ?

Comment: actually, by request the type it should have to show me the own created location which is registered on google as same like other near location for type are coming , but its only showing the other details now my own created location.

Comment: even when i searched the same location by name on maps.google.com its not showing me that location , if this location is registered on google than it should have to show me that on maps

Comment: Can you put the code for how are you showing the location on Map ?

Comment: i am not showing location on map , i am trying to fetch my location by passing my location type , my api key , so in response its providing me all near location with requested type , so it should have to come my  own created location as well , but its not coming :(

Comment: by requesting with location id its coming in response , but i want that by passing location type , code i have put above how i am requesting near all location by passing location type.